# S3 presigned url doesn't work when generated with a lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, boto3

The following code, I got from this [Boto3 S3 Example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html), works properly both if launched locally and from a lambda function executed with a call to the API Gateway:

```
   s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
   response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post("mybucket",
                                                "myfile.jpg"
                                                ExpiresIn=3600)
```

In both cases it returns a response like the following:

```
{
    "url": "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    "fields": {
        "key": "myfile.jpg",
        "AWSAccessKeyId": "-omissis-",
        "policy": "eyJle...dfQ==",
        "signature": "ruboM...P3R4c="
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two is that the remote one (generated by the lambda function) includes also the field `x-amz-security-token`.

```
...
        "x-amz-security-token": "IQoJb...ZAQ==",
...
```

When I try to POST the file (using the html example reported in the page linked above or postman), everything works properly when I use the presigned url generated locally (whitout `x-amz-security-token`) but it fails when I try the one generated remotely.

It returns the following error message when `x-amz-security-token` is sent as form's field:

```
403 Forbidden

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>-omissis-</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId>360...BE2</RequestId>
    <HostId>y04bl...DWhqY=</HostId>
</Error>
```

and the following as header's field:

```
403 Forbidden

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>No AWSAccessKey was presented.</Message>
    <RequestId>A7592...6681</RequestId>
    <HostId>stc/+...eeUU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

How should I properly make the POST request when the presigned url includes `x-amz-security-token`?

Comment: Can you show us what your request looks like in Postman?

Comment: Lambda IAM role has access to s3 bucket? if Lambda doesn't have access to S3 objects, signed url generated by Lambda will not have access either!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same case from an ECS task. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I am also running into the same problem with ECS. Running the same container/service locally doesn't get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using Lambda, since you don't use access keys, but it rather assumes a role through its IAM execution role (STS). This means that for each execution it generates temporary credentials with short expiry and uses them to execute whatever it needs (in this case, pre-signing a URL).

When actually downloading/uploading from the client-side, you need to send **X-Amz-Security-Token** in the body with the value you get when pre-signing. Unfortunately this is not clearly documented by AWS.

On the server-side, in NodeJS generating the `sessionToken` would be:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const credentials = s3.config.credentials;
const sessionToken = credentials.sessionToken;
```

On the server-side, in PHP generating the `sessionToken` would be:

```
$credentials = $s3client->getCredentials()->wait();
$sessionToken = $credentials->getSecurityToken();
```

And on the client-side when uploading/downloading the file, you would send this as Body:

```
"acl": presignUploadData.acl, // for upload
"key": presignUploadData.key, // the key you presigned for download/upload
"X-Amz-Credential": presignUploadData.XAmzCredential,
"X-Amz-Algorithm": presignUploadData.XAmzAlgorithm,
"X-Amz-Date": presignUploadData.XAmzDate,
"Policy": presignUploadData.Policy,
"X-Amz-Signature": presignUploadData.XAmzSignature,
"X-Amz-Security-Token": presignUploadData.XAmzSecurityToken, // this is the new part
```

This fixes the **403 Forbidden** part.

If you get `Access Denied`, that could be a permission issue, the most classic being granting access to the resource `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME` but not to `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*` or not granting sufficient s3 permissions.

To speed things up, you can try `"s3:*"` on `"Resource": "*"` to see if it works, then start restricting both the permission and the resource (for security's sake, don't skip this part).